# What is the appropriate name for this dataset?

Tags: dataset, data, cross-validation

I'll assume most of us know about cross-validation and are accustomed to using Training and Test sets. However, I've also seen references to a third set that you use to test a completed model. It's the test to see how your model does against a dataset that it hasn't seen before; helps determine if your model has been overly-fit to the training data.

I have seen this dataset referred to everything from "the third dataset", "the wild dataset", "the real-world dataset". So what is the appropriate name for this third dataset?

Comment: Well, I would not call this "Test" set you defined as "Test"! I would say: Train, Validation, Test. And this "Test" is the dataset that your model has not seen yet. This is pretty standard even explained in details in Andrew Ng courses.

Comment: @MajidMortazavi if you want to post this as an answer, I choose it as the correct one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I would not call this "Test" set you defined as "Test"! I would say: Train, Validation, Test. And this "Test" is the dataset that your model has not seen yet. This is pretty standard even explained in details in Andrew Ng courses like this very useful and [important lesson](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M3qpIzy4MQk) on splitting data and the significance of their distributions.